# Matrix finite groups

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, linear-transformations

I’m studiying finite groups of linear transformations under matrix multiplication.
So far, i’ve encountered that:

On an arbitrary base field $\mathbf{F}$ with characteristic $\#(\mathbf{F})=0$:

- Some matrices $M$ with determinant $Det(M)=1$ form a finite group under multiplication.
- Every permutation matrix $P\in\mathbf{S}_n$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $\mathbf{C}_k$ under multiplication whenever the associated cycle $\sigma\cong P\in\mathbf{S}_n$ is a k-cycle.
- The Special Linear Group $SL_n$ and all it’s finite subgroups (they have also a unital determinant).
- Diagonal matrices with n-th roots of unity as inputs.
- …

Every one of these matrix examples seems to fulfill the condition that for any matrix M:
$$|Det(M)|=1$$
Is the preceding identity (with $|\cdot|$ being the absolute value function on the base field) a necessary and sufficient condition for a Matrix group to be finite?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: your first bullet that  "Every matrix $M$ with determinant $Det(M)=1$ forms a finite group under multiplication" isn't true and in fact the answer you accepted has an example contradicting this.

Comment: Thanks, i edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, there is not such a thing as **the** absolute value on the base field.  There can be lots of them.

Necessary: yes (for any absolute value on the base field).  If $|\det(M)|\ne 1$, the determinants of $M^k$ for integers $k$ are all distinct, so the group generated by $M$ is infinite.

Sufficient: no.  For example, if $\theta$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, the group generated by the rotation $\pmatrix{\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\cr \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\cr}$ is infinite.